# How to run launchd agent/daemon from a NSApplication?

Tags: macos, cocoa, launchd

In my NSApplication I've a button. When I click it, I want to launch/start a daemon/agent. How can I proceed? I've already tried:

```
- (void) runAgent {
    NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    task.launchPath = @"launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.mycompany.myagent.plist";
    [task setLaunchPath:@"/bin/sh"];
    [task launch];
}
```

with no success...

Answer (score 1):

```
    NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    [task setLaunchPath:@"/bin/launchctl"];
    [task setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"load",@"/System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.mycompany.myagent.plist", nil]];
    [task launch];
```